# What setting do I need to modify to make the current file more obvious in the VS 2013 Editor?

Tags: tabs, ide, visual-studio-2013, themes, code-editor

This is what I see in my current project:

[image]

At first glance (to me, YMMV), none of these files really "stands out"; the featured file (no pun intended) is "FeatureAuthorizeAttribute" which *is* different from the others in that the font is bolded, HOWEVER I would like an even more immediately obvious visual c[l]ue of which is the current file.

What setting is needed to make the current file "pop" more?

### UPDATE

I do have PPT (as recommended by Yann Duran (wasn't that the name of an 80s band?)) and, though I thought "Custom Document Well" was a typo, it's not). I have the settings as he suggested:

[image]

...but the current tab still does not "jump out" at me; I reckon I'll have to live with identifying the bolded tab. I would really prefer an animated gif of a dancing duckbilled platypus or something, though (I'd settle for a bear, pig, or kitty-kat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the [Productivity Power Tools for VS 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) extension installed, I highly recommend that you download & install it.

There are a number of productivity enhancements that it offers, including the ability to "*Color tabs by project*", or "*Color tabs by regular expression*". After you've installed the extension, these options are found by selecting:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Power Productivity Tools
4. Custom Document Well

Another possibility would be the Theme Editor extension that someone in Microsoft released.

Answer (score 1):

The color theme extension lets you colorize the active tab with a bright color but I can only get it to work when I switch the colorization in productivity power tools off.

For now I'm using only the color theme extension but if I can get the theme options to take priority over the productivity power tools I'll post here.

Color theme editor:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b/view/Discussions

Productivity power tools:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef